# Kafka: MessageSizeTooLargeException when increasing batch size

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, size

I'm ussing kafka4net API to send kafka messages.
The messages have a lenght of 10kb aprox and contain the bytes of binary files.
I have to read the binary files from the filesystem and send it via Kafka.

I have a loop to make this task in batches of 100 files. I download the files from my intranet and then I send them via kafka. (i.e, I download 100 files, then I read 100 files and send 100 kafka messages). It works well. But I realized that if I use 1000 files loops a MessageTooLargeException is thrown.

The kafka messages size remains constant, the only thing that changes is the batch size (there's a peak of messages because 1000 messages are sent in a little amount of time instead of 100 messages).

If I increase the size on this two configuration properties:

```
replica.fetch.max.bytes
message.max.bytes
```

and on the following property in the consumer

```
message.max.bytes
```

I get it working. As soon as I increase the batch size (or send the same message several times which causes the same effect), the error appears again.

I don't understand why this configuration properties have relation with this issue, because they affect to the size of one single message, not to the batch size, or buffer size or queue size of whatever is increased when sending a lot of messages at the same time.

¿What should I consider to config when sending a lot of messages in a short time to avoid this kind of errors and why does this error happen?

Thank you!